# Help with this recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
6, & n=0 \\
9T(n-2)+n, & n>0
\end{cases}
$$

I don't know how to resolve this.....Can you tell me how can I solve it?

Comment: I can't read the question.  There seems to be something missing.  Please clarify

Comment: There is a missing initial condition - what is $T(1)$? Without this information, we cannot for example compute $T(3)$.

Comment: Have you tried the methods explained in Wilf's "generatingfunctionology", my favourite reference for this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to follow it a couple of terms and see the pattern. So assuming $n = 2m$ is even,
$$
\begin{split}
T(n)
&= 9T(n-2)+n \\
&= 9 (9T(n-4) + (n-2)) + n\\
&= 9^2T(n-4) + 9(n-2) + n \\
&= 9^3 T(n-6) + 9^2 (n-4) + 9(n-2) + n \\
&\ldots \\
&= 9^m T(0) + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 9^k (n-2k)
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish it? (Note: if $n = 2m+1$ is odd, you will end up with $9^mT(1)$ in the last term and some other related changes will be needed.)

A different way is to propose a solution of the form $T(n) = a^n$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, plug it in and see what values of $a$ will fit...

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then it will be $T(1)$ in the last step of the calculation.

Comment: @Kumar made the changes